# How to find current user location to use in Google Places API for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps, core-location

I'm looking to use this Google Places API url to search in an iOS app. Instead of using the designated location I would like to use the user's current location:

```
NSURL *googlePlacesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=500&types=spa&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAgcp4KtiTYifDSkIqd4-1IPBHCsU0r2_I"];
```

Would it be a matter of storing the users current location lat/lon and then placing those values in the NSURL?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URl shows that you want to list place near by current location.

for that you need current location coordinates, radius, searched place name and key.

Do this:

Step 1: Add CoreLocation framework

Step 2: #import

Step 3: Add CLLocationManagerDelegate delegate

Step 4: Make     CLLocationManager *locationManager;

Step 5: Initialise CLLocationManager ( usually in ViewDidLoad)

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];// autorelease];
// This is the most important property to set for the manager. It ultimately determines how the manager will
// attempt to acquire location and thus, the amount of power that will be consumed.
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest ;
// Once configured, the location manager must be "started".
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];   
locationManager.delegate = self;
```

Step 6: Write code for CLLocationManager

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{ 
    StrCurrentLongitude=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude]; // string value
    StrCurrentLatitude=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    appDeleg.newlocation=newLocation;
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; // string Value
}
```

Step 7: Use coordinates and fire request :

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=%@,%@&radius=%@&name=%@&sensor=false&key=YOU-API-KEY",StrCurrentLatitude,StrCurrentLongitude,appDeleg.strRadius,strSelectedCategory]
```

ENJOY

Comment: Please note that the delegate method
    `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation`

is deprecated in iOS 6.0 & it is advised to use 

    `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations`

Refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)